# ejabberd The ejabberd.yaml configuration of my two servers is the same, why the interface format of the requested API is inconsistent

Tags: ejabberd-api, ejabberd-auth

one: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.99:5443/api/status

```
"The node ejabberd@localhost is started. Status: startedejabberd 0.0.0 is running in that node"
```

two: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.214:5443/api/status

```
{
"status": "error",
"code": 32,
"message": "AccessRules: Account does not have the right to perform the operation."
}
```

ejabberd.yaml configuration :

```
listen:
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      /api: mod_http_api
      /oauth: ejabberd_oauth

oauth_expire: 3600
oauth_access: all
```

Need to return data in JSON format, it should be mod_http_api processed.

I could not get through this error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The configuration file is identical? And the account with admin rights that you use to perform the query exists in both servers?